# What is the best way to ask a question?

Tags: discussion, support, downvotes

Can anyone suggest me, the best way to ask a question, so that, it does not get edited and also not get down-votes? Basically, i need to improve my grammar, and what else?

Comment: Why are edits such a bad thing? BTW - it is not possible to guarantee that you will not get downvotes.

Comment: [ask] is where I point everyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Keep on topic.
2. Ask an actual question, about an actual problem you are facing.
3. Ask **after** doing some research yourself.
4. Post your findings.
5. Ensure your grammar and spelling are correct.
6. Search the site for the answer before posting your question.
7. Follow the help center [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.
8. Follow the http://sscce.org guidelines.
9. Follow the [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) guidelines.
10. Don't look for discussions.
11. Don't ask for opinions or recommendations.
12. Post the relevant code. No less, no more.

The more of the above you can manage, the better.